# the arrays with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I would like to have an array like this (1) :

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([ (1, 2, 9.799, 4.7, 4.77, 148929.0, 450030016.0),
(11, 21, 91.799, 41.7, 41.77, 1489129.0, 4500130016.0),
(41, 25, 93.799, 74.7, 94.77, 1487929.0, 4500340016.0)],
dtype = [('a', '<i4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('e', '<f4'), ('r', '<f4'), ('t', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('u', '<f4')])
```

Using this :

```
A = np.array([])
A = np.append(A,(1, 2, 9.799, 4.7, 4.77, 148929.0, 450030016.0))
A = np.append(A,(11, 21, 91.799, 41.7, 41.77, 1489129.0, 4500130016.0))
A = np.append(A,(41, 25, 93.799, 74.7, 94.77, 1487929.0, 4500340016.0))
```

But the problem is I get only

```
array([ 1, 2, 9.799, 4.7, 4.77, 148929.0, 450030016.0,
11, 21, 91.799, 41.7, 41.77, 1489129.0, 4500130016.0,
41, 25, 93.799, 74.7, 94.77, 1487929.0, 4500340016.0  ])
```

without the parenthesis like in (1) and also I don't know how fix the dtype doing like this...

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Don't try to treat arrays like lists; repeatedly `append`-ing to an array is an extremely inefficient way of working with arrays.

Comment: No where in the `Using this` block are you specifying the `dtype`.  `numpy` does not infer a compound dtype like this from the elements of a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
l = []
l.append((1, 2, 9.799, 4.7, 4.77, 148929.0, 450030016.0))
l.append((11, 21, 91.799, 41.7, 41.77, 1489129.0, 4500130016.0))
l.append((41, 25, 93.799, 74.7, 94.77, 1487929.0, 4500340016.0))
A = np.array(l, dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('e', '<f4'), ('r', '<f4'), ('t', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('u', '<f4')])
```